# onClick function active by default

Tags: javascript

I find it very complex to create a separate menu for mobile/small screen devices, so I decided to go with the main one, however my goal is to display all the links by default (when loading the page), actually the user needs to click on a small icon to display the dropdowdown links, it's very popular practise and most users are comfortable with that however my client insist on showing all links without clicking on anything.

I managed to hide that icon but I'm stuck because I cannot display those links anymore, is there a way to activate that onClick function by default? Or maybe disable dropdown secondary list on mobile?

The code below is navigation:

```
NavigationView.prototype.initialize = function() {
  this.$el.on('click', (function(_this) {
    return function(e) {
      if (!$(e.target).closest('.navigation').length) {
        return _this.$('.navigation .open').removeClass('open');
      }
    };
  })(this));
  this.$el.on('focus', '.header-navigation-link.primary-link', (function(_this) {
    return function() {
      var $menuWrapper;
      $menuWrapper = $(_this.$el.find('.has-dropdown.open'));
      if ($menuWrapper.length) {
        return $menuWrapper.toggleClass('open', false);
      }
    };
  })(this));
  return this.$el.on('focus', '[data-is-dropdown] .secondary-link', (function(_this) {
    return function(event) {
      var $target;
      $target = $(event.currentTarget);
      return $target.parents('.has-dropdown').toggleClass('open', true);
    };
  })(this));
};

NavigationView.prototype.toggleNavigation = function(e) {
  var $target;
  $target = $(e.target);
  if ($target.parents().hasClass('has-dropdown')) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return $target.parent().toggleClass('open');
  }
};

return NavigationView;
```

What I'm trying to change is that ToggleClass; active by default so don't need to click on icon to show secondary-list

Comment: can't you add `open` class by default in html code?

Comment: @nitishkumar-singh it's a shopify website, html is generated automatically

Comment: might try to use **$( document ).ready()** then access the drop down and apply the class to open it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the syntax you are looking for:

```js
this.$el.on('click', myFunction); //runs myFunction onclick

function myFunction() {
  //display dropdown code here
}

myFunction(); //runs myFunction onload
```